# How To Check If A Receiving Contract Emitted An Event With Ethersjs?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

In the context of testing using hardhat...

**The scenario:** My `token` is transfering from `owner` to `receiverContract`. I want to check that receiverContract emitted a `Received` event.

The transaction looks like this and is initiated by the owner.

```js
const tx = await token.transferFrom(
  owner.address, // <- From this wallet
  receiverContract.address, // <- To this contract
  tokenId,
  {
    from: owner.address,
  }
);
```

How can I check if receiverContract emitted a "Received" event?
Alternatively, if someone can solve this problem with `@openzeppelin/test-helpers` `expectEvent.inTransaction()` that works too.

Edit: The receiver contract code emits an event when it receives something. So we can assume it emits. I just need to write a test for it. I'm not interested in testing for the `Transfer` event on the token itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

Each contract can be viewed via `console.log(receiverContract)`... so I eventually navigated to the event object inside the contract. Here is a snippet of the contract when logged...

```js
{
  interface: Interface {
    fragments: [ [ConstructorFragment], [EventFragment], [FunctionFragment] ],
    _abiCoder: AbiCoder { coerceFunc: null },
    functions: {
      'onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)': [FunctionFragment]
    },
    errors: {},
    events: { // <- This is what we're looking for
      'Received(address,address,uint256,bytes,uint256)': [EventFragment {
    name: 'Received',
    anonymous: false,
    inputs: [ [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType] ],
    type: 'event',
    _isFragment: true
  }],
  // ...
}
```

Running `console.log(receiverContract.interface.events)` gives you this nested object

```js
  'Received(address,address,uint256,bytes,uint256)',
  EventFragment {
    name: 'Received', // <- This is the event name
    anonymous: false,
    inputs: [ [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType], [ParamType] ],
    type: 'event',
    _isFragment: true
  }
```

So in order to look for and test that the event emitted, this works

```js
expect(
  Object.entries(receiverContract.interface.events).some(
    ([k, v]: any) => v.name === "Received"
  )
).to.be.equal(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no interaction with the receiving contract, it will not emit anything.

Transaction is sent to the token, which emits `Transfer` event once it changes records of its ledger.

You can watch the token for `Transfer` event, or read the transaction receipt, decode the log and check for that event.

Answer (score 0):

The ERC20 contract transaction is sent to the token contract itself, and not to the receiving contract, hence there cannot be any event emitted from the receiving contract.

A receiving contract can emit any event only if it has been configured in either the `receive()` or `fallback()` method. That too, while sending `msg.value` to it i.e. ETH, BNB, etc. (the receiving contract's chain's native crypto).

If you just want to make sure that the receiving contract has received the tokens, you can check the `Transfer` event emitted by the ERC20 token contract.

You want suggestions on `@openzeppelin/test-helpers`, I've not used it but you can use the `expectEvent()` function to check it.

Something like (NOT TESTED):

```
const tx = await token.transferFrom(
  owner.address, // <- From this wallet
  receiverContract.address, // <- To this contract
  tokenId,
  {
    from: owner.address,
  }
);

expectEvent(tx, 'Transfer', {
  from: owner.address, // <- From this wallet
  to: receiverContract.address, // <- To this contract
  value: tokenId,
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I simplified my question in my post. The contract itself has a function that emits a "Received" event whenever it receives something. I should have asked more generally.. how can I check that a receiving contract emits an event using ethers/hardhat/hardhat-waffle. I see an example using Truffle and `@openzeppelin/test-helpers` but not sure how to approach it with hardhat/ethers/hardhat-waffle. The OZ solution above only works for transfer on the token contract but not for a receiving contract emitting. `expectEvent.inTransaction` works for Truffle but syntax unclear with ethers

Comment: I figured out how to do it thanks.